# Footer keeps moving up when I delete row from table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hey everyone so I've got a page on my website which shows a list with the supply and demand information in a table and I've got a button for each row which deletes the row of data. But every time I delete a row the footer moves up the page and when I delete all of the rows so there is no data left it just shows the table headings with no rows. But I want the footer to stay at the bottom and also I still want to show the row even if there is no data, but just an empty row. So how can I do this? Here is my code but it doesn't work:

```
 <TableStyle>
      <THead quiet={quiet}>
        <tr>
          {keysToRender.map((item, i) => (
            <Th key={i}>
              {customKeyNames[item] ? customKeyNames[item] : item}
            </Th>
          ))}
          {buttons &&
            buttons.map((item, i) => <Th key={i}>{item.tableHeader}</Th>)}
          {icons && icons.map((item, i) => <Th key={i}>{item.tableHeader}</Th>)}
        </tr>
      </THead>
      <TBody quiet={quiet}>
        {data &&
          data.map((row, i) => (
            <Tr key={i} order={i} quiet={quiet}>
              {data.length === 0 && <Td>-</Td>}
              {keysToRender.map((item, i2) => (
                <Td order={i2} divider={divider} key={i2}>
                  {row[item]}
                </Td>
              ))}
```

This is what it looks like when there is no data in the table: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8bZB.png)

This is what it looks like with data in the table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmBam.png)

So I've added a min height of 300 px to the div around the table but there's still a problem when there is a lot of rows so I need pagination but how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what exactly your page looks like.
If I correctly understand your quastion, you need to make content growable.

```
<div class='page'>
    <div class='content'>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class='footer'>
        ...
    </div>
</div>


// styles
.page {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

'content' - it's your table